Why RealDigits[0.0401] gives {{4, 0, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9}, -1}?
I find two cases in which RealDigits behaves differently than expected. I understand that it gives a list of the digits in the approximate real number but cannot get the point why the approximation of 0.0401(0.00401) is 0.040099..(0.0040099..) while some others are not.
RealDigits[0.401]


{{4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 0}

RealDigits[0.0401]


{{4, 0, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9}, -1}

RealDigits[0.00401]


{{4, 0, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9}, -2}

RealDigits[0.000401]


{{4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, -3}

RealDigits[0.0301]


{{3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, -1}

RealDigits[0.0501]


{{5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, -1}

RealDigits[0.04001]


{{4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, -1}


This has to do with IEEE 754 binary representation of double-precision numbers. Please read up on these – your question has nothing to do with Mathematica. The exact number represented by 0.401, for example, is SetPrecision[0.401, ∞], which gives 1805943450575569/4503599627370496 and is clearly different from 401/1000 (the denominator must be a power of 2, not 10, in IEEE 754 binary representation).

Thank you Roman. It looks like by default RealDigits uses SetPrecision[x, 16] for the approximate. Given higher accuracy we would see different result.

Yes, $MachinePrecision is 15.9546 digits these days. Again, this comes from IEEE 754 double-precision numbers. If you want to do numerical math on a computer, you will need to learn about the details of these representations.

See this or that prior MSE posts.
